# ajax suggestion box not working on windows 11 if logged in as an administrator

Tags: ajax, windows, administrator, suggestbox

For a text form on my site, I have a suggestion box that delivers matches from a database for possible results as the user types. However, on windows 11 the text disappears as soon as it is selected from the suggestion box. This occurs both in chrome and edge but happens only if I am logged into windows as an administrator. Do you have an idea what is going on?

I have tried this on linux computers, mac and on windows as non-administrator and the page works fine but not if I am logged on to my PC as administrator

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here is my code on the: